# Pinia store don't update the i18n when swich language

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia, vue-i18n

I have an issue with Pinia store and i18n translation.

I'm quite new using Pinia (with typescript) and I'm trying to use i18n for the first time too.

I made a language switcher and it seems to work well except for the values taken from the pinia store.

If I use the simple interpolation in the template it works but if I use a value from a pinia store I can't see the translation, except when I refresh the page with a different language parameter in the URL.

This is my router

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: `/${i18n.global.locale.value}`
    },
    {   
      path: '/:lang',
      component: {
        render() { return h(resolveComponent('router-view')) }
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/:lang/',
          name: 'home',
          component: HomeView
        },
        {
          path: '/:lang/about',
          name: 'about',
          component: AboutView
        },
        {
          path: '/:lang/services',
          name: 'services',
          component: ServicesView
        },
        {
          path: '/:lang/contacts',
          name: 'contacts',
          component: ContactsView
        },
        {
          path: '/:lang/404',
          name: '404',
          component: NotFoundView
        },
      ] 
    },
  ]
})

// use beforeEach route guard to set the language
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  // use the language from the routing param or default language
  let language = to.params.lang;
  if (!language) {
    language = 'en'
  }

  // set the current language for i18n.
  i18n.global.locale.value = language

  next()
})



export default router
```

this is my i18n plugin

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
  import en from '../locales/en.json'
  import fr from '../locales/fr.json'

  const instance = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: import.meta.env.VITE_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
    fallbackLocale: import.meta.env.VITE_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'fr',
    messages: {
      en,
      fr
    },
  // to silent the fallback warnings for i18n. this is a known bug
    fallbackWarn: false,
    missingWarn: false,
    globalInjection: true,
  })

export default instance;
export const i18n = instance.global;
```

My i18n store

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { i18n } from '@/plugins/i18n';


export const useI18nStore = defineStore('i18nStore', () => {
  const t = useI18n({ inheritLocale: true, useScope: 'local', fallbackWarn: false })
  
  const setNewLanguage = (language: string) => {
    i18n.locale.value = language;
    console.log(i18n.locale.value , "from store I18n")
  }
  
  return { t, setNewLanguage }
})
```

and this is a Store, where I use the i18n that works only when I reload the page with the language code /en/ or /fr/ but not with the router.push

```
import { ref} from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useI18nStore } from '../stores/i18nStore'
//images


interface ServiceOffered{
  title: String,
  imgUrl: String,
  text: String,
  cta: String
}

export const useOfferedServicesStore = defineStore('offeredServices', () => {
  const translation = useI18nStore();
  const { t } = translation.t;

  const offeredServices = ref<Array<ServiceOffered>>(
    [
      {
        title: "",
        imgUrl: "",
        text: t('offeredServicesCard1'),
        cta:  t('discoverMore')
      },
      {
        title: "",
        imgUrl: "",
        text: t('offeredServicesCard2'),
        cta: t('discoverMore')
      },
      {
        title: "",
        imgUrl: "",
        text: t('offeredServicesCard3'),
        cta: t('discoverMore')
      },
      {
        title: "",
        imgUrl: "",
        text: t('offeredServicesCard4'),
        cta: t('discoverMore')
      }
    ]
  );

  return { offeredServices }
})
```

I think it may be an issue of reactivity of the pinia store but I'm not sure and I have tried the storeToRefs too but maybe in the wrong way.

Can anyone had the same issue?

I hope you can help me with that.

Thank you so much.

I tried to switch language with the i18n in pinia store but the template don't render the translation but only the fallback. It happens when I use router.push but when I refresh the page with a different code language it works.

I hope to make the switch language with the pinia store works well.

Comment: Have you tried setting the text and cta attributes as functions? Translated strings in objects wont be updated when the language is changed. Strings in templates or functions will be updated.

So you could use the function variant a such:
text: () => t('offeredServicesCard1'),

Or just store the string and translate in the template:
text: 'offeredServicesCard2',
And in the template:
{{ $t(offeredServices[0].text) }}